# Js $(this) не указывает на объект

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Добрый день, помогите понять из-за чего в $(this) не содержится ссылки на вызвавший объект. Пытаюсь сделать следующие ф-ии:

```
function onHover() {$('#item-bottom-img-main').attr('src', $(this).attr('href')); }
function outHover() {$('#item-bottom-img-main').attr('src', $("#item-bottom-img-main-a").attr('href')); }
```

Но `this` возвращает Window Object, т.е. атрибут href = undefined

Цель: Поменять большую картинку при hover на маленькое изображение, реализую через onmouseover=""

Спасибо

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь сделать-то?

Comment: Потому что Вы вызываете Ваши функции вот так: `onHover();` и `outHover();`.

Comment: А как его тогда вызвать можно ?

Comment: @KamilNHOT покажите код, который использует `onHover` и `outHover`